# Não envia email com PHP mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
<?php

// Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php localizado na pasta class
require_once("a/class.phpmailer.php");
require_once("a/class.smtp.php");

// Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

// Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP

try {
     $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // Endereço do servidor SMTP (Autenticação, utilize o host smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
     $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  // Usar autenticação SMTP (obrigatório para smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
     $mail->Port       = 587; //  Usar 587 porta SMTP
     $mail->Username = 'evertonradical@gmail.com'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP (endereço de email)
     $mail->Password = 'SENHA'; // Senha do servidor SMTP (senha do email usado)

     //Define o remetente
     // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=    
     $mail->SetFrom('severtonradical@gmail.com', 'Nome'); //Seu e-mail
     $mail->AddReplyTo('severtonradical@gmail.com', 'Nome'); //Seu e-mail
     $mail->Subject = 'Assunto';//Assunto do e-mail


     //Define os destinatário(s)
     //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
     $mail->AddAddress('jose.everton.f@hotmail.com', 'Teste Locaweb');

     //Campos abaixo são opcionais 
     //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
     //$mail->AddCC('destinarario@dominio.com.br', 'Destinatario'); // Copia
     //$mail->AddBCC('destinatario_oculto@dominio.com.br', 'Destinatario2`'); // Cópia Oculta
     //$mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');      // Adicionar um anexo


     //Define o corpo do email
     $mail->MsgHTML('corpo do email'); 

     ////Caso queira colocar o conteudo de um arquivo utilize o método abaixo ao invés da mensagem no corpo do e-mail.
     //$mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('arquivo.html'));

     $mail->Send();
     echo "Mensagem enviada com sucesso</p>\n";

    //caso apresente algum erro é apresentado abaixo com essa exceção.
    }catch (phpmailerException $e) {
      echo $e->errorMessage(); //Mensagem de erro costumizada do PHPMailer
}
?>
```

Porem não estou conseguindo enviar, aparece esse erro:

```
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

Alguem sabe como faço?

Comment: Você alterou o nome do arquivo ? _class.phpmailer.php_ ?

Comment: Não, mais vou baixar mais uma vez aqui e tentar.

Comment: Acho que você não está se autenticando corretamente o STMP na hora de enviar.

Comment: Seu servidor é o problema. Está bloqueando.

Answer (score 0):

Então, acho que você precisa também importar o arquivo PHPMailerAutoLoad.php.

sempre uso este código aqui e dá certo, tente ele...

```
<?php
session_start();
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$mensagem = $_POST["mensagem"];

require_once("PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "email@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "123456";

$mail->setFrom("email@gmail.com", "Titulo");
$mail->addAddress("email@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Email de contato da loja";
$mail->msgHTML("<html>de: {$nome}<br/>email: {$email}<br/>mensagem: {$mensagem}</html>");
$mail->AltBody = "de: {$nome}\nemail:{$email}\nmensagem: {$mensagem}";

if($mail->send()) {
    $_SESSION["success"] = "Mensagem enviada com sucesso";
    header("Location: index.php");
} else {
    $_SESSION["danger"] = "Erro ao enviar mensagem " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    header("Location: contato.php");
}
die();
```

Answer (score -1):

Pelo fato da porta ser 587, acho que deve colocar

> $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';